How to get matched pattern in ugrep
I have created a ugrep command and file
ugrep -Hn -e 'Error:XX234 - \S+\.txt : cannot find user' -e 'Error:XX235 - \S+\.pdf : cannot find data' --format='%f:%n:%o%~'  *

File content
1_Error0: rwPqdEPE.txt - YjTccJITSpALx1B8cORN
ErrorXX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data
Error:XX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data
Error:XX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user

Output
enter image description here
I am expecting below in the output:

display which pattern was matched with error

Above is just a sample ugrep command. my actual command will be quite big like below
ugrep -Hn -e pattern1 -e pattern2 -e patternN --format='%f:%n:%o%~' *

Expected output
issue.txt:12:Error:XX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data:<pattern2>
issue.txt:13:Error:XX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user:<patternN>

Problem Statement to be solved
I am working on a solution to help my clients who use my application (AppX) troubleshoot issues. For example, when clients try to install AppX, there are certain services that must be running. If these services are not running, AppX logs an error message in the log files.
This is just one type of issue; there can be many such issues reflected in the log files.
Currently, the Support Team analyzes these log files manually to identify the issues and provide resolutions to the clients. Given that there could be thousands of such issues and the log files can be large and in formats like .tar or .zip, this manual process is time-consuming and inefficient.
I am developing a tool to automate this process. The tool will:

Allow users to upload log files.
Automatically scan the uploaded log files for known issues based on a database of error messages and their corresponding resolutions.
If a known issue is found, the tool
will provide a direct link to the resolution based on the data stored in the database.

This will streamline the troubleshooting process, making it faster and more efficient for the Support Team to provide resolutions to clients.
So I am saving such issues as a part of string or regex pattern and their resolution link mapped in DB and later on I want to fetch the error matched in log file and present the team with resolution link

I strongly support the answer from @Ed Morton. In your problem description the matching strings are not patterns but strings. A hashing solution is better. And it is possible that there could be different problems associated on a single error message (for example variety of SQL errors).

We can print the matched pattern in the output using '%G' option.
ugrep -rHPn -o -e '(?<pattern1>ErrorXX234 - \S+\.txt : cannot find user)' -e '(?<pattern2>ErrorXX235 - \S+\.pdf : cannot find data)' -e '(?<pattern3>pattern1 pattern2)' --format='--%M--%F:%n:%o:%G---%~' *

Output
--1--issue.txt::1:ErrorXX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user:pattern1---

--2--issue.txt::2:ErrorXX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data:pattern2---

--3--issue.txt::4:pattern1 pattern2:pattern3---

--4--issue.txt::7:ErrorXX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user:pattern1---

--5--issue.txt::9:ErrorXX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user:pattern1---

--6--issue.txt::10:ErrorXX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data:pattern2---

--1--testfile copy 2.txt::14:ErrorXX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user:pattern1---


Keep in mind this quote:

Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

You may not need any regexps, or not as many as you think you do, e.g. this, which will work in any awk, uses literal strings and hash lookups of error string "patterns" so it'll be very fast and may be functionally adequate for your needs for all we know from the posted example:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = ":" }
NR == FNR {
    errs[$0]
    next
}
{
    key = $0
    sub(/- [^.]+\./,"- .",key)
}
key in errs {
    print FILENAME, NR, $0, key
}


$ awk -f tst.awk errs.txt issue.txt
issue.txt:5:Error:XX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data:Error:XX235 - .pdf : cannot find data
issue.txt:6:Error:XX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user:Error:XX234 - .txt : cannot find user


$ cat errs.txt
Error:XX234 - .txt : cannot find user
Error:XX235 - .pdf : cannot find data


$ cat issue.txt
1_Error0: rwPqdEPE.txt - YjTccJITSpALx1B8cORN
ErrorXX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data
Error:XX235 - xyz.pdf : cannot find data
Error:XX234 - abc.txt : cannot find user

That works by instead of trying to match every regexp in a long list of regexps, removing from every input line the parts that would match \S in your regexp and then just doing a hash lookup to see if the result matches one of the target error messages read from errs.txt.

Hi @Ed Morton, I have rephrased and defined my exact problem statement above. Thanks

@SushantThakuryou added an explanation of why you want a solution, but it doesn't really tell us anything that would help you come up with a solution. We still don't know what these log file contain, what the "known issues based on a database of error messages" contains, what a "a direct link to the resolution based on the data stored in the database" means, etc. From everything I've read so far without more information about the log files, errors database, and required output, I still think my answer sounds so far like what you need

Apologies, If I was not able to communicate the problem precisely. Thanks for your time and response. I found what I was looking for.
Appreciate your time.
